# Use enum values for switch

Tags: java, enums

I've class Aligment like below:

```
public enum Aligment
    {
        Evil,
        Neutral,
        Good,
        Undefined
    }
```

And I want to use these values in switch like so:

```
System.out.print("Choose you'r start up character" +
                     "1.Good" +
                     "2.Evil" +
                     "3.Neutral");
    //1  string alignmentChoice = scan.nextLine();
    //2  Aligment alignmentChoice = Aligment.Undefined;
    switch( aligmentChoice )
    {
       case Good:
        alignment = Aligment.Good;
        break;

       case Evil:
        alignment = Aligment.Evil;
        break;

       case Neutral:
        alignment = Aligment.Neutral;
        break;

       default:
        System.out.println("How did you manage to get here? You have broke the system.");
        break;

     }
```

And I'm not sure how to use it like //1 or //2. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You use it like option #2. Go ahead and try it and see for yourself! If `aligmentChoise` is of the type `Alignment` (which is an enum), you should be able to go ahead and do it this way. Note that I'm specifically talking about how to use the enum with the switch statement. Converting user input to enum is a separate matter (do something like `Alignment.values()[index]` if you are asking the user for a number input.)

Comment: Did you mean "Good", "Evil" in the case statements?

Answer (score 4):

Use it like so :

```
switch(Aligment.valueOf(alignmentChoise)) {
   case Evil: 
     alignment = Aligment.Evil;
     break;
}
```

Note : 
This will throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the enum constant is not found.

Comment: You are missing a `)`.

Comment: @Michael : Hence the note!

Comment: @Glains : Thanks for that. Edited the answer.

Comment: @NicholasK The note does not explain that. Enum constants are just identifiers - variable names. Variable names should not have an impact on the runtime behaviour of an application, that should be obvious. If some other developer decides to refactor your code to change the name of the constant - maybe to make it upper case, which they should be - then they've unintentionally broken the code because of a bad design decision that you made.

Comment: Ok. I took it the other way then. Although your point is valid I'm just trying to answer the question, rather than refactor the code.

Comment: That's fine. Everyone has a different opinion of everything, you do and so do I. I provided an answer that doesn't change the original question too much. *Maybe that's what really OP wants or maybe not also*. I don't believe my answer is wrong. Still harsh on the down-vote, you can't expect every answer to refactor the code in a question.

Comment: Of course you don't. Again, the question was on how to use a switch with an enum value. I provided an answer to address the *immediate problem* without much change to the original question..

Comment: @NicholasK Without heavily prefacing your answer with "**this is bad**", you are advocating that what you have shown is a good way to accomplish the given task. 
You may not think that you are, but you are. By solving "the *immediate problem*" in this way, you're not helping anyone to do anything other than write bad code

Comment: *Without heavily prefacing your answer with "this is bad"* -- too late for that. Last time I checked this was stackoverflow and not [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's [not too late](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53229697/edit) for anything. I would be perfectly happy to reverse my vote if you would improve this to an acceptable answer, but you seem quite content to needlessly defend how bad it is. That's all I have to say, so have a good weekend. Ping me if you choose to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

If you refactor and move this switch case logic to a method in your enum, you no longer need to use a switch statement for getting an enum from a string.

In the following example, I have added a method `fromString()` which will take a string input `name`, and compare with all of our enum values (case unsensitive).

If a matching value is not found, we throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Here is the example:

```
public class AlignmentTest{

     public static void main(String[] args){

        String good = "good";
        String neutral = "NEUTRAL";
        String evil = "EvIl";
        String unknown = "unknown";

        Alignment alignment1 = Alignment.fromString(good);
        System.out.println("Alignment 1: " + alignment1);

        Alignment alignment2 = Alignment.fromString(neutral);
        System.out.println("Alignment 2: " + alignment2);

        Alignment alignment3 = Alignment.fromString(evil);
        System.out.println("Alignment 3: " + alignment3);

        Alignment alignment4 = Alignment.fromString(unknown);
        System.out.println("Alignment 4: " + alignment4);
     }

     public enum Alignment {   
        EVIL("Evil"),
        NEUTRAL("Neutral"),
        GOOD("Good");

        private String name;

        Alignment(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public static Alignment fromString(String name) {
            for (Alignment alignment : Alignment.values()) {
                if (alignment.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    return alignment;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No alignment with name " + name + " found");
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Alignment 1: GOOD
Alignment 2: NEUTRAL
Alignment 3: EVIL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No alignment with name unknown found
    at AlignmentTest$Alignment.fromString(AlignmentTest.java:44)
    at AlignmentTest.main(AlignmentTest.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping (static map) inside your enum for holding the map between the *name* to be provided by the user to the enum.

```
public enum Alignment {
    Evil("Evil"),
    Neutral("Neutral"),
    Good("Good"),
    Undefined("Undefined");

    private static final Map<String, Alignment> MAPPINGS = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Alignment alignment : Alignment.values()) {
            MAPPINGS.put(alignment.getName(), alignment);
        }
    }

    private String name;
    Alignment(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Alignment getAlignmentForName(String name) {
        return MAPPINGS.get(name);
    }
```

Now, you can use `getAlignmentForName` to map the user input to an enum. It will return `null` for invalid values.

The advantage of this is that you need not change any code when you add a new enum instance... In your case, an appropriate switch case has to be added.

*Note:* The names of enum fields must be in uppercase letters as per the [conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: While we're at it, enum members should be uppercase, since they are constants. Pascal case makes them look like inner classes.